# Making a javascript call work for multiple div boxes

Tags: javascript, zeroclipboard

I've got the following JavaScript code, which works great for the divs "from" and "copy" (when the user clicks "copy" it copys from "from"). I'm using ZeroClipboard.

```
clip.addEventListener('mouseDown', function() {
var pre = document.getElementById('from');
clip.setText(pre.innerHTML);
});

clip.glue('copy');
```

However, I want this to work for multiple divs - now it only works for the first one. I'm no JS expert so I humbly ask of you to explain how to do this. I'll use PHP to name my divs from1, from2, from3 etc and copy1, copy2, copy3 respectively.

Comment: Do you want to learn javascript or just make some code that works fast and easy? If the ladder, then check out jQuery. With that you could target all div's using $('div).dosomething_or_some_action()

Comment: Depends on your definition of fast. JQuery is fast to write, but if you don't use it properly it causes a lot of overhead...

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div')` and then iterate over the `divs` object.

Answer (score 0):

Steve's answer will work for all divs on the page. Assuming you have some divs that you don't want copied, a better solution will be:

```
var pre = document.getElementsByClassName('copy');
```

Amd then using a `for` to itterate the resulting array.

```
for(i=0; i<pre.length; i++){
    clip.setText(pre[i].innerHTML);
}
```